# Error in installation of skimage binary on Windows

Tags: python

`>pip3 install T:\RNA\Baltimore\Jason\python_binaries\scikit_image-0.11.3-cp35-none-win_amd64.whl`

Several hundred lines fly by during installation without error, but it ends on this:

```
Processing t:\rna\baltimore\jason\python_binaries\scikit_image-0.11.3-cp35-none-win_amd64.whl
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): six>=1.3 in e:\users\hackr\python\python35\lib\site-packages (from scikit-image==0.11.3)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pillow>=1.7.8 in e:\users\hackr\python\python35\lib\site-packages (from scikit-image==0.11.3)
Collecting networkx>=1.8 (from scikit-image==0.11.3)
  Using cached networkx-1.10.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): matplotlib>=1.1.0 in e:\users\hackr\python\python35\lib\site-packages (from scikit-image==0.11.3)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): decorator>=3.4.0 in e:\users\hackr\python\python35\lib\site-packages (from networkx>=1.8->scikit-image==0.11.3)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): cycler in e:\users\hackr\python\python35\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib>=1.1.0->scikit-image==0.11.3)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pyparsing!=2.0.4,>=1.5.6 in e:\users\hackr\python\python35\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib>=1.1.0->scikit-image==0.11.3)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): numpy>=1.6 in e:\users\hackr\python\python35\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib>=1.1.0->scikit-image==0.11.3)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pytz in e:\users\hackr\python\python35\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib>=1.1.0->scikit-image==0.11.3)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): python-dateutil in e:\users\hackr\python\python35\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib>=1.1.0->scikit-image==0.11.3)
Installing collected packages: networkx, scikit-image
  Running setup.py install for networkx
    Complete output from command e:\users\hackr\python\python35\python.exe -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\hackr\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\3\\pip-build-zqydf0yg\\networkx\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\hackr\AppData\Local\Temp\3\pip-6skb2q_j-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib
    creating build\lib\networkx
    copying networkx\convert.py -> build\lib\networkx
    copying networkx\convert_matrix.py -> build\lib\networkx
    copying networkx\exception.py -> build\lib\networkx
    copying networkx\relabel.py -> build\lib\networkx
    copying networkx\release.py -> build\lib\networkx
    copying networkx\version.py -> build\lib\networkx
    copying networkx\__init__.py -> build\lib\networkx
    creating build\lib\networkx\algorithms
    copying networkx\algorithms\block.py -> build\lib\networkx\algorithms
    copying networkx\algorithms\boundary.py -> build\lib\networkx\algorithms
    copying networkx\algorithms\clique.py -> build\lib\networkx\algorithms
    copying networkx\algorithms\cluster.py -> build\lib\networkx\algorithms
    copying networkx\algorithms\core.py -> build\lib\networkx\algorithms
    copying networkx\algorithms\cycles.py -> build\lib\networkx\algorithms
    copying networkx\algorithms\dag.py -> build\lib\networkx\algorithms
    copying networkx\algorithms\distance_measures.py -> build\lib\networkx\algorithms
    copying networkx\algorithms\distance_regular.py -> build\lib\networkx\algorithms
    copying networkx\algorithms\dominance.py -> build\lib\networkx\algorithms
    copying networkx\algorithms\dominating.py -> build\lib\networkx\algorithms
    copying networkx\algorithms\euler.py -> build\lib\networkx\algorithms
    copying networkx\algorithms\graphical.py -> build\lib\networkx\algorithms
    copying networkx\algorithms\hierarchy.py -> build\lib\networkx\algorithms
    copying networkx\algorithms\hybrid.py -> build\lib\networkx\algorithms
    copying networkx\algorithms\isolate.py -> build\lib\networkx\algorithms
    copying networkx\algorithms\link_prediction.py -> build\lib\networkx\algorithms
    copying networkx\algorithms\matching.py -> build\lib\networkx\algorithms
    copying networkx\algorithms\minors.py -> build\lib\networkx\algorithms
    copying networkx\algorithms\mis.py -> build\lib\networkx\algorithms
    copying networkx\algorithms\mst.py -> build\lib\networkx\algorithms
    copying networkx\algorithms\richclub.py -> build\lib\networkx\algorithms
    copying networkx\algorithms\simple_paths.py -> build\lib\networkx\algorithms
    copying networkx\algorithms\smetric.py -> build\lib\networkx\algorithms
    copying networkx\algorithms\swap.py -> build\lib\networkx\algorithms
    copying networkx\algorithms\triads.py -> build\lib\networkx\algorithms
    copying networkx\algorithms\vitality.py -> build\lib\networkx\algorithms
    copying networkx\algorithms\__init__.py -> build\lib\networkx\algorithms
    creating build\lib\networkx\algorithms\assortativity
    copying networkx\algorithms\assortativity\connectivity.py -> build\lib\networkx\algorithms\assortativity
    copying networkx\algorithms\assortativity\correlation.py -> build\lib\networkx\algorithms\assortativity
    copying networkx\algorithms\assortativity\mixing.py -> build\lib\networkx\algorithms\assortativity
```

[several thousand lines omitted here to make it fit]

```
    copying examples\algorithms\hartford_drug.edgelist -> e:\users\hackr\python\python35\share\doc\networkx-1.10\examples\algorithms
    copying examples\basic\properties.py -> e:\users\hackr\python\python35\share\doc\networkx-1.10\examples\basic
    copying examples\basic\read_write.py -> e:\users\hackr\python\python35\share\doc\networkx-1.10\examples\basic
    copying examples\3d_drawing\mayavi2_spring.py -> e:\users\hackr\python\python35\share\doc\networkx-1.10\examples\3d_drawing
    error: can't copy 'examples\drawing\atlas.py': doesn't exist or not a regular file

    ----------------------------------------


Command "e:\users\hackr\python\python35\python.exe -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\hackr\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\3\\pip-build-rk1n4got\\networkx\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(to
kenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\hackr\AppData\Local\Temp\3\pip-wi6hs7db-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally
-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\hackr\AppData\Local\Temp\3\pip-build-rk1n4got\networkx`
```

Comment: Please check the logs carefully: actual error should be somewhere above this line. It usually goes like: `actual error message ... some more text before script is finished ... message about script failing with error code`

Comment: @Lav I tried to pull the log but strangely there's no folder where it's indicated. I have a `\AppData\Local\Temp\3` but the folder after that doesn't exist...

Comment: I mean the same log from where you pasted the error message. If you're having issues finding the error in console output, run `pip3 install blah-blah-blah.whl > pip3.log` to dump your installation log to a text file and then browse it at will.

Comment: BTW I recommend to report this issue to scikit-image team. It's not certain that it's their issue, but if installing networkx separately works without problems, then maybe they're referencing an incorrect build or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And here's the culprit:

```
error: can't copy 'examples\drawing\atlas.py': doesn't exist or not a regular file
```

It seems something's wrong with the installation package for [`networkx` library](http://networkx.github.io/) that `scikit-image` is trying to install as a dependency. Try installing `networkx` manually before installing `scikit-image`. If the problem persists, that's something you should report to [networkx bugtracker](https://github.com/networkx/networkx/issues/) I guess. If it works however, then I recommend to report it to `scikit-image` team - maybe they're referencing an incorrect build or something as their dependency.